# How can I make my disk not spin down while writing backups to it?

Tags: server, 20.04, hdparm

I use a 1TB hard drive to store backups for my system. I write backups once every night.

I have tried to configure my hdparm.conf to spin down after 30 mins of being inactive

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/783E797F3E7936EA {
    spindown_time = 254
}
```

Creating my backup and writing to my disk takes something like 20 minutes. During this write process my disk spins up and down many many times making irritating noises.

I suspect this is because linux caches the writes to the disk and writes them every now and then instead of continuously writing to the disk keeping it active.

How can I make the disk spin up once when the backup writing starts, stay active through the whole job, and in the end spin down until the next time I try to read/write from it?

I'm running Ubuntu server 20.04.1.

EDIT:

I am sure my UUID is correct, I got it from running `blkid` and I am using it in my `/etc/fstab` which is working without a problem.

Running `hdparm -S 60 /dev/disk/by-uuid/783E797F3E7936EA` achieves what I want to happen, but I want it to be done with configuration. Not by running commands every now and then.

EDIT 2:

My backups are simple tar archives of my home folders. These contain all files that are important to me. It runs as a cronjob once a day. The command doing the work in my backup script is `tar -cJpf <archive name> /home`.

I know the disk is spinning down. I can feel it stop moving with my hands when it has been inactive for a short period of time. I can also hear the speed of the disk ramping up from 0 RPM to operating speed whenever I access it after it has been spun down.

The disk is very freshly partitioned with a single large partition and should not have any problem with fragmentation.

Comment: How do you run your backups? Is it an application that was installed or something you scripted?

Comment: How do you know the drive is "spinning down" and not just seeking to non-contiguous areas of the disk?  If this happens every day and it's not being defragrmented regularly, my guess is that the disk has to jump all over the place to store your backups.

Comment: @Matigo I have updated the question with answers to your questions.

Comment: @Nmath I have updated the question with answers to your questions.

Comment: Is that 1 TB drive an external USB Seagate drive?

Comment: @Stormlord No it is a normal internal 1TB SATA drive.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to write a script that contains the `hdparm` changes and have your cron job call that.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /backup/location
hdparm -S 0 /dev/disk/by-uuid/783E797F3E7936EA
ar -cJpf <archive name> /home
hdparm -S 60 /dev/disk/by-uuid/783E797F3E7936EA
```

Set the file to be executable with a `chmod +x` and  give it a test in the console.

Notes:

- be sure to change `/backup/location` to where you actually want your backups written
- using `hdparm -S 60 {device}` will wind that device down after 5 minutes of inactivity. 30 minutes is generally not feasible as the number works in increments of 5 seconds between 1 and 240. For more info, [the docs outline exactly how to use the numbers](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/hdparm.8.html)

Hope this gives you what you're looking for.

Comment: This would work, but I think this should be possible to solve with configuration.